# Carry observations forward based on increasing values by group

Tags: r

I think I have an easy question but I am looking for the more efficient (in terms of computing power required) way to do the following.
I have a dataset with thousands of columns and I would simply like to locf (carry forward last observation) for each one of them.
The only condition I need to respect is that the highest value is carried forward

My data looks something like this

```r
df <- data.frame("ID" = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Beta", "Beta", "Beta", "Beta", "Beta"), "Year" = c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010), "Var" = c(NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 2, NA), "otherVar" = c(NA, 2.34, 1.3, NA, NA, 1.3, NA, 3.5, 1.5, NA))
df
#>       ID Year Var otherVar
#> 1  Alpha 1970  NA       NA
#> 2  Alpha 1980  NA     2.34
#> 3  Alpha 1990   0     1.30
#> 4  Alpha 2000  NA       NA
#> 5  Alpha 2010  NA       NA
#> 6   Beta 1970  NA     1.30
#> 7   Beta 1980   1       NA
#> 8   Beta 1990  NA     3.50
#> 9   Beta 2000   2     1.50
#> 10  Beta 2010  NA       NA
```

And I would like to obtain the following data

```
final <- data.frame("ID" = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Beta", "Beta", "Beta", "Beta", "Beta"), "Year" = c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010), "Var" = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 1, 1, 2, 2), "otherVar" = c(NA, 2.34, 2.34, 2.34, 2.34, 1.3, 1.3, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5))
final
#>       ID Year Var otherVar
#> 1  Alpha 1970  NA       NA
#> 2  Alpha 1980  NA     2.34
#> 3  Alpha 1990   0     2.34
#> 4  Alpha 2000   0     2.34
#> 5  Alpha 2010   0     2.34
#> 6   Beta 1970  NA     1.30
#> 7   Beta 1980   1     1.30
#> 8   Beta 1990   1     3.50
#> 9   Beta 2000   2     3.50
#> 10  Beta 2010   2     3.50
```

As I mentioned the idea is that for each one of my variables I would like to fill NAs with the last observation carried forward. But I would want only to retain the highest value. For instance `otherVar` in 1970 was 1.3 so this value was carried forward to 1980 to fill NA. In 1990 the value of `otherVar` is 3.5, so it "takes the place" of 1.3 and the score of `otherVar` in 1990 is 3.5. Finally, in 2000 the score of `otherVar` is 1.5. since 1.5< 3.5, in the final dataset the higher value is carried forward.

I would like to find the least computationally-intensive method to do this since I have to do it for thousands of variables.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Best regards

Comment: Sounds like `cummax` to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cummax` after `replace`ing the NA with 0 and later change back the 0 to `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate_at(3:4,  ~ na_if(cummax(replace_na(., -999)), -999))
```

Comment: great solution.-  At least I thought on the first glance. But it does not fully fulfill the OP request- see what happens in group Beta

Comment: Thanks Akrun! I was wondering if there is a possibility to use a positional identifier for `vars()` because variable not necessarily share same name. Also, dplyr tends to be very slow on large dataset and I have million of observations. is ther a way to make it more efficient?

Comment: I think you need `cummax` not `max`, and deal with NAs.

Comment: I was trying this solution but it does not seem to work perfectly. Apparently it just changes the `var` and `othervar` score to the maximum per ID. rather than carry forward observations

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I changed it

Comment: @Alex Since performance is important, translating this answer to `data.table` may be an additional step worth taking.

Comment: Thanks @Akrun, it works well now. :). Any idea about how to improve performance as well? Perhaps a `data.table` solution as @Axeman suggests?

Comment: @Alex You can use `data.table` `set` methods for changing the values or try `setDT(df)[, (3:4) := lapply(.SD, function(x) cummax(replace(x, is.na(x), 0))), ID, .SDcols = 3:4]`

Comment: Thanks this is great @Akrun

Comment: I have noticed that the `data.table` command automatically changes `NAs` to 0s, is there a way to keep NA when there is no value carried forward like in the `final` dataset in row 1?

Comment: @Alex  You meant in the `data.table` right?  I changed it to 0.  You can change the 0s back to `NA` as in the solution with `dplyr` i..e `df[, (3:4) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x==0, NA)), .SDcols = 3:4]`

Comment: thanks, but I  just realized this could be a problem, because I have certain variables with 0 values in the columns, and they are meaningful.. I have edited the `dt` to be more accurate. iI Is there a way that does not require replacing all the NAs, but rely on locaf?

Comment: @Alex Okay in that case, change it to a value that wouldn't normally occur.  I change it to `-999`